# how to convert stereo audio to mono?

Tags: ios, audio

Nowadays, I'm developing an app for iPhone in which I want to play an audio in left channel and right channel seperately (ps:The audio played is muti-channel), up to now, I have tried many ways, for example, finding some properties(e.g. setPan:) which I can set to do this, but failed,so,what should I do with this problem, could you please give me some suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: did you find a solution for this? i need to do something similar - i need to be able to play just the left or right channel from a stereo source (to correct for errors in source material). i'd like to be able to take the left channel from the source and play it on both channels. (or vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

For manipulating audio at the channel level, see the AVAudioSession class in AVFoundation in the docs that come with Xcode.

In particular, the *Audio Session Programming Guide*.

Answer (score 0):

I think Novocaine library will be helpful. You can go through 
[this example](https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP).

It'll help you for sure. In example, you can alter following method

`- (void)filterData:(float *)data numFrames:(UInt32)numFrames numChannels:(UInt32)numChannels`

in NVDSP.mm file to get what you want.

Comment: I’d like to offer what I’m going to call here 100% person opinion — but only because to call it otherwise would require me to provide exhaustive references — but a strong rule of thumb in platform programming — especially when the platform provides such direct and low- or no-friction Frameworks/APIs is to much prefer those over 3rd party APIs. If you read Steve Jobs’ (now considered a treatise, even prophesy if a self-fulfilling one) on Flash when iPhoneOS was new (not even called iOS yet) and many were clamoring for Flash video playback be supported.

Answer (score 0):

One easy, powerful, free and maintained solution to manipulate audio in iOS is [AudioKit](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit). Through it you can create something like this:

```
leftSignal = AKBooster(input)
leftSignal.rightGain = 0
leftPannedRight = AKPanner(leftSignal, pan: 0.5)

mixer = AKMixer(leftPannedRight)
AudioKit.output = mixer
```

It's a great solution to audio without the need to deal with low level frameworks. To help you start, there is a lot of tutorials online and answered questions for AudioKit here at StackOverflow. A nice start is with the [AudioKit's playgrounds](https://audiokit.io/playgrounds/).